# How Would I Make This Code Add a Line to Allow for More Lines to be Filled for the CSV

Tags: php, html

So I have built a very basic form to take a client's information and export it to a csv file. The next thing to learn is how to make it where multiple lines can be added. I basically want a button that says, "Add a line" and then it recreates the existing form and exports that data to a second line on the csv file. I would like this option to be repeatable so they could add as many lines as needed.

The form in it's current state is working but mostly useless until I can create an option to add a line.

```
<?php
// Initialize the $errors array
$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Collect form data
    $Companyname = $_POST['Companyname'];
    $firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $lastname = $_POST['LastName'];
    $DateofBirth = $_POST['DateofBirth'];
    $CDL = $_POST['CDL'];
    $Country = $_POST['Country'];
    $State = $_POST['State'];

    // Validate First Name
    if (empty($firstname)) {
        $errors[] = "First Name is required.";
    }

    // Validate Last Name
    if (empty($lastname)) {
        $errors[] = "Last Name is required.";
    }

    // Validate Date of Birth
    if (empty($DateofBirth)) {
        $errors[] = "Date of Birth is required.";
    }

    // Validate CDL
    if (empty($CDL)) {
        $errors[] = "CDL # is required.";
    }

    // Validate Country
    if (empty($Country)) {
        $errors[] = "Country is required.";
    }

    // Validate State
    if (empty($State)) {
        $errors[] = "State is required.";
    }

    // If there are no errors, proceed
    if (empty($errors)) {

        // Title of the CSV
        $Content = "firstname,lastname,DateofBirth,CDL,Country,State\n";

        // Set the data of the CSV
        $Content .= "$firstname,$lastname,$DateofBirth,$CDL,$Country,$State\n";

        // Set the file name and create CSV file
        $FileName = $Companyname . "-" . date("d-m-y-h:i:s") . ".csv";
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"');
        echo $Content;
        exit();
    }
}

//if there are errors, display them
if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo '<p style="color:#ff0000">' . $error . '</p>';
    }
}
?>

<!-- HTML Form -->
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Companyname" required="" value="">
    <br>
    <label>First</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" required="" value="">

    <label>Last</label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" required="" value="">

    <label>DOB</label>
    <input type="date" name="DateofBirth" required="" value="">

    <label>CDL #</label>
    <input type="text" name="CDL" required="" value="">

    <label>Country</label>
    <select name="Country" required="">
        <option value="">Select a country</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="CN">Canada</option>
        <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    </select>

    <label>State:</label>
    <select name="State" required="">
        <option value="">Select a state</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusettes</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get CSV">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
    <input type="submit" name="addline" value="Add a line">
</form>

</form>
```

Comment: This should be done in JavaScript. PHP only runs when the user submits the form, it can't make live changes to the page.

Comment: To add multiple lines to the CSV file, you can modify your PHP code to store the form data in an array and loop through the array to append each line to the CSV file. Is that what you want?

Comment: Either add more fields to the input form, or use Javascript. [to add more fields to the input form]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple way to add multiple lines into your form with JavaScript.  This is just a demo, so modify it as you need so that you are sending the correct form names to your PHP as you need them.

```js
//Select some elements
const lineTemplate = document.querySelector('#csv-line-template');
const lineOutput = document.querySelector('#line-output');
const btnAddLine = document.querySelector('#btn-addline');
let lineCount = 0;

function addLine(){
  //Copy the template
  const clone = lineTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  //remove the ID from the template since we can't duplicate an ID and this ID is what keeps the template hidden
  clone.removeAttribute('id');
  
  //Loop through every input element inside the clone and update them to have a unique name by adding a number at the end
  //modify this as needed depending on what you need in PHP
  Array.from(clone.querySelectorAll('input, select'))
    .forEach(el => {
      el.name += '-' + lineCount;
    });
  
  //Put the cloned element into the form
  lineOutput.appendChild(clone);
  
  //increase the count for the next time a line is added
  lineCount++;
}

//Click the button to add a line
btnAddLine.addEventListener('click', addLine);

//Add one line by default
addLine();
```

```css
.csv-line {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#csv-line-template{ display: none; }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div id="line-output"></div>
  
  <input type="button" id="btn-addline" value="Add a line">
  
  <hr/>
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get CSV">
  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
  
</form>

<div class="csv-line" id="csv-line-template">
  <label>Company Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Companyname" required="" value="">
  <br>
  <label>First</label>
  <input type="text" name="FirstName" required="" value="">

  <label>Last</label>
  <input type="text" name="LastName" required="" value="">

  <label>DOB</label>
  <input type="date" name="DateofBirth" required="" value="">

  <label>CDL #</label>
  <input type="text" name="CDL" required="" value="">

  <label>Country</label>
  <select name="Country" required="">
      <option value="">Select a country</option>
      <option value="US">United States</option>
      <option value="CN">Canada</option>
      <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
  </select>

  <label>State:</label>
  <select name="State" required="">
    <option value="">Select a state</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusettes</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```